# Highlight max/min on MultiIndex DataFrame - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Assume to have a 2 layers MultiIndex dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['one', 'A', 100,3], ['two', 'A', 101, 4], 
                   ['three', 'A', 102, 6], ['one', 'B', 103, 6], 
                   ['two', 'B', 104, 0], ['three', 'B', 105, 3]],
   columns=['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']).set_index(['c1', 'c2']).sort_index()
print(df)
```

which looks like this one

```
           c3  c4
c1    c2         
one   A   100   3
      B   103   6
three A   102   6
      B   105   3
two   A   101   4
      B   104   0
```

My goal is to highlight (with Pandas's styling) the minimum (or equivalently the maximum) between the elements of `'c2'` for all the columns `'c3'` and `'c4'` for each element in `'c1'`

```
             c3      c4
c1    c2         
one   A   **100**   **3**
      B     103       6
three A   **102**     6
      B     105     **3**
two   A   **101**     4
      B     104     **0**
```

Do you have any suggestion?

I already tried this one, but it works column-wise and not based on the index.

```py
def highlight_min(data):

    attr = 'background-color: {}'.format(color)

    if data.ndim == 1:  # Series from .apply(axis=0) or axis=1
        is_max = data == data.min()
        return [attr if v else '' for v in is_max]
    else:  # from .apply(axis=None)
        is_max = data == data.min().min()
        return pd.DataFrame(np.where(is_max, attr, ''),
                            index=data.index, columns=data.columns)

df = df.style.apply(highlight_min, axis=0)
```

The results if the following

```
             c3      c4
c1    c2         
one   A   **100**     3
      B     103       6
three A     102       6
      B     105       3
two   A     101       4
      B     104     **0**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `min` and compare by all values:

```
def highlight_min(data):
    color= 'red'
    attr = 'background-color: {}'.format(color)

    if data.ndim == 1:  # Series from .apply(axis=0) or axis=1
        is_min = data == data.min()
        return [attr if v else '' for v in is_min]
    else: 
        is_min = data.groupby(level=0).transform('min') == data
        return pd.DataFrame(np.where(is_min, attr, ''),
                            index=data.index, columns=data.columns)
```