# Highlight max/min on MultiIndex DataFrame - Pandas solution not working for me. But why?

Tags: python, pandas

I am faced with the exact problem listed in this posting ([Highlight max/min on MultiIndex DataFrame - Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55688221/highlight-max-min-on-multiindex-dataframe-pandas)), my table is even exactly as OP had posted.

But when I tried the solution, it seems to go back to highlighting just the minimum for each column. Why?

My output for reference.
[image: 1]

It went back to highlighting the min value for the overall column, not for each subindex.

Comment: Please keep the pictures to a minimum. Share code as text ([ask])

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out haha...axis parameter in last line of code needs to equal None so code should be

```
def highlight_min(data):
color= 'red'
attr = 'background-color : {}'.format(color)

if data.ndim == 1:  # Series from .apply(axis=0) or axis=1
    is_min = data == data.min()
    return [attr if v else '' for v in is_min]
else: 
    is_min = data.groupby(level=0).transform('min') == data
    return pd.DataFrame(np.where(is_min, attr, ''),
                        index=data.index, columns=data.columns)

df.style.apply(highlight_min,axis=None)
```